# Xcode does not open on Mac yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: xcode

My Xcode got crash and it does not open when I try to reopen. I've tried to open other versions of Xcode from applications too. None of the Xcode app responding.
I've tried  restarting the Machine too. No luck. When I try to open from terminal (using `sudo open --new /Applications/Xcode.app`).
I'm getting this error

> LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file
>   /Applications/Xcode.app.

I've got wasted lot of time on this. Please help me out.

Comment: What's your XCode version? Did you try to update XCode?

Comment: Its xcode 6.3.1.I've tried installing new xcode too..When it shows the alert 'Xcode is installed from internet,would you like to open it ?After clicking on 'open'  nothing happens

Comment: Did you try to right click XCode and click Open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Xcode installation seems corrupted. Delete and reinstall Xcode from the app store.

Comment: Thanks,This has worked for me...I've downloaded xcode and opened it directly without copying to applications.